# jQuery callbacks apparently repeat on failure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, error-handling, callback

I seem to be observing at least one case where a callback function passed to a jQuery effect function will execute repeatedly if there's an error while it's executing.

For example, see [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJZrh/), featuring the following code:

```
$('#awesome').fadeOut(400,function () {
    log('fading out...');
    dieInAFire();
});
```

`log` appends whatever's passed to it to a div... but `dieInAFire` doesn't exist. Rather simply stopping execution, however, the anonymous function appears to be getting called over and over, as evidenced by the growing number of appearances of 'fading out...' in the log div.

Is this the expected behavior? If so, why?

Comment: amazing discoveries ... :-) To me it's not expected at all.

Comment: Very weird, looks like it has something to do with the animation. AJAX callbacks don't have this issue, and this callback is fine too if there is no animation. IE if the element already has the style `display: none;` the callback is called exactly one time. Same problem occurs with fadeIn() too

Comment: Actually it occurs with just plain old `.animate()` no matter what css styles you are animating it seems

Comment: I just noticed the exact same behavior with a callback today. Except mine was on a plugin i created. called using `..,function(){alert('hello world');});` and in the plugin executed with `callback.call(this);` There was however an error with another plugin I was calling after the alert. so presumably it is on all callbacks invoked within the jquery object?

Comment: There is an error around here in the function step: `options.complete.call( elem );` in jQuery. If an error is thrown in te callback then the function doesn't return true or false, it seems a boolean must be returned (not undefined) for the step function to ever stop executing.

Comment: If you wrap it in a `try catch` the error goes away, (callback is only executed once), but of course then we have the undesirable affects of no exceptions seemingly being thrown by the callback.

Comment: This was fixed in jQuery version 7: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/yJZrh/25/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug. [See the report here.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5684)

Answer (score 1):

I just submitted a comment on the bug that patrick dw posted.

Changing the line:

```
options.complete.call(elem);
```

To:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    options.complete.call(elem);
}, 0);
```

Causes the callback to execute asynchronously, and if it will no longer stop execution if it throws any errors. IMO it's better than using a `try catch` since it doesn't suppress the exception.

If you want to edit your minified version, and you use the latest jQuery, you can search for `e.complete.call(d)` and replace it with `setTimeout(function(){e.complete.call(d)},0)`